# How to Package and provide web app in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I have web application tar file. I have created docker image for the same. I will be using a private docker registry (Due to security reasons). I have written Helm charts to use the image in Kubernetes (Kept it in Private helm repo). So if anyone want to install the APP using docker image on EKS feature of AWS, what would be the best way I can package my app and give it to them ?

Basic requirement is It shouldn't be available to everyone for installation. Only the one's approved by me can install.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push it to their private container registry. If they are using AWS you can use [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/). You can find more information on how to push the image [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html)

Basically, they would need to create an [IAM user/role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_IAM_policies.html) for you to be able to push to their AWS account.